# How to customize signup fields in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, register

I want to customize my input fields on the register page for my Magento `webshop` and add some fields.

I already tried some extensions but the customer attributes are only showing on the backend `(By customer's personal information)` and on the fronted `(When the customer is already logged in)`.

The problem is that the fields aren't showing on the Sign Up page.

> Magento version: 1.9.2.4

Ps: I am really new in magento, so don't make it to hard for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer help you then mark as accepted so other user take benefit when they have face same problem

Answer (score 0):

go to your `/app/design/frontend/Yourpackage/Yourtheme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

and add filed it will autometically save in database,

But make sure you gave field `Id` and `name` is same as your customer `attribute_code`.